# How to resolve the Java Exception In Initialize error?

Tags: java, kotlin, exception, pdfbox, pdf-extraction

I am creating an app where I can extract the text from the pdf. For this I am using PdfBox library. But when I import pdf from the file manager, app stops and it gives exception in Initialize error at line where PDFTextStripper is initialized. How can I solve this problem?

Below is the function for extracting the text from pdf.

```
private fun extractTextPdfFile() {
   var document: PDDocument? = null
    var parsedText: String? = null
    try {
        val inputStream: InputStream? = this.contentResolver.openInputStream(fileUri!!)
        document = PDDocument.load(inputStream)
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    try {
        val pdfStripper = PDFTextStripper()
        pdfStripper.startPage = 0
        if (document != null) {
            pdfStripper.endPage = 1
        }
        parsedText="Parsed text: " + pdfStripper.getText(document)
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } finally {
        try {
            document?.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.file_path).text=parsedText

 }
}
```

I have used registerForActivityResult for getting the pdf document Uri.

```
private var fileUri: Uri? = null
private val getContent =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
        // Handle the returned Uri
        if (uri != null) {
            fileUri = uri
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Cannot fetch document from the file manager",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
    }
  
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    findViewById<Button>(R.id.Import).setOnClickListener {
        getContent.launch("application/pdf")
        if (fileUri != null)
            extractTextPdfFile()
    }
}
```

This is the exception which I am getting. I don't know how it is now giving null pointer exception, earlier it was giving the exception which I had mentioned.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.InputStream.close()' on a null object reference
    at com.tom_roush.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.<clinit>(PDFTextStripper.java:1874)
    at com.example.doctranslator.MainActivity.extractTextPdfFile(MainActivity.kt:82) 
    at com.example.doctranslator.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda-1(MainActivity.kt:44) 
    at com.example.doctranslator.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$8z4EEPr6Q6JatIakz-DO65v-zdE(Unknown Source:0) 
    at com.example.doctranslator.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:8160) 
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16222) 
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:8137) 
    at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:888) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30236) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8595) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
```

Comment: Can you post the full exception message (including stack trace)?

Comment: I added the exception but it is now giving null pointer exception. I am confused as I didn't changed the code.

Comment: There's a problem with your jar file, make sure that "com/tom_roush/pdfbox/resources/text/BidiMirroring.txt" exists. Have a look at https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/tom_roush/pdfbox/text/PDFTextStripper.java#L1855 , input would be null if the resource doesn't exist.

Comment: How can I add this .txt file in my project. I just added the dependency of pdfBox for its implementation. Please help me with this.

Comment: First make sure you are using maven. Second, try if it works with a previous version. I can't help directly because I don't have an android build environment set up. You should try using a previous version, but also report the bug on the bug tracker. Mention that the file is missing and the null check is missing. I looked into the .aar (not .jar) file and it is missing. https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/tom-roush/pdfbox-android/2.0.3.0/

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you haven't called `PDFBoxResourceLoader.init(Context)` before using PDFTextStripper. This is required to load certain files used by PdfBox-Android like BidiMirroring.txt.

I added `PDFBoxResourceLoader.init(applicationContext)` to your `onCreate` function and was able to extract text successfully using your code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the PdfBox library is getting compiled into your code? Because if its an error which happens on initialization it seems to be a compilation error since it cannot refer to the library.

You should get some kotlin code to compile your dependencies into your built app.